# Comparing MongoDB documents of different collections with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hi I would like to compare two documents of different databases with each other to say if they are equal or not. At first I printed both objects calling them with their identifier:

```
newi=[i for i in new.find({'RefData.Ident.Id':'D004'})]
print(newi)
oldi=[i for i in old.find({'RefData.Ident.Id':'D004'})]
print(oldi)
```

Unfortunately, both print a large list and it is really troublesome to compare these two by hand (and also not possible because it needs to be done with at least 100documents). Apart from comparing every attribute with each other (there are too many), is there a way to compare the whole document at once with the other one?

Answer (score 0):

If the two documents are exactly identical (including whitespace), you could strip out the _id field then compare the hash of the documents.

Otherwise, you will need to perform element by element comparisons which could be coded in python.